# Java - ClassCastException while retrieving query result of type User & casting it to User (Same Class)

Tags: java, jpa, glassfish, ejb

Code:

```
User user = (User) entityManager.createNamedQuery("User.login")
                .setParameter("username", username)
                .setParameter("password", password).getSingleResult();
```

Query:

```
"select u from User u where u.userName=:username AND u.password=:password"
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: warehouseProject.model.User cannot be cast to warehouseProject.model.User
```

I searched, All I found that it may be a classloader issue, so I wrote the following code to test & both User classes seem to have the same class loader

```
ClassLoader loader1 = User.class.getClassLoader();
System.out.println("MyEntity's class loader is " + loader1);

ClassLoader loader2 = obj.getClass().getClassLoader();
System.out.println("MyQuery's class loader is " + loader2);
```

Result:

```
Info: MyEntity's class loader is WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/)
Info: MyQuery's class loader is WebappClassLoader (delegate=true)
```

I am using ejb 3, JPA 2 with hibernate as a provider, eclipse IDE, glassfish 4

Note: I tried to return the username as a string from the query instead of the user & it works fine, so it's not a database or datasource problem.

Any suggestions???

Comment: Looks like a code change didn't arrive at the server. Did you try to Clean & Build your project before deploying it again?

Answer (score 0):

It's always problem of different classloaders. Please, check your project, may be User.class loaded twice, for example, separately in server and client part of the application. In your test classloaders are different on my mind.

Comment: Class User only exist once I am sure.
but how are the classloaders different, explain more please??

Comment: Pay attention on your test results: the "same" classloader returned different result of toString() call. It is only my assumption. Would be good to perform more deeper diagnostic procedure.